# Margins will not adjust to make a smaller chart?

Tags: highcharts

I have the following pie chart but cannot figure out how to get the margins to move closer to the rendered pie chart itself. I need to squeeze into some smaller real estate and it's overlapping other divs

Fiddle->http://jsfiddle.net/8EZM4/

[image]

```
<div id="container3" class="container3" style="width: 120px; height: 130px; margin: -25px 0px -80px -20px; padding-bottom: -10px; border-width:1px; border-style: solid"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts leaves room for the labels and titles, etc.  A couple of things to do to get rid of the space:

- Set the spacing and margin to zero
- Set the size of the pie chart

It seems to me one or the other should work.  But, if I just do the 1st, the chart is a little too small and if I just do the 2nd, the chart is a little too big.

```
$('#container').highcharts({    
    chart: {
        type:'pie',
        borderWidth: 1,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        spacingBottom: 0,
        spacingTop:0,
        spacingLeft:0,
        spacingRight:0,
        margin: [0, 0, 0, 0]
    },

    title: {
        text:''
    },
    plotOptions: { 
        pie: {
            size:300,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J3ZFf/

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.size

Comment: Awesome! It looks like it combination of the two! Fiddle->http://jsfiddle.net/qVV85/3/  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by what is wrong. The div containing the chart is 120px by 130px. That is setting the size of the black border, and if anything is too big, this div must be made smaller first. Beyond that, eliminating the margins and spacing will do the trick as Mrs Laird said.

Comment: Look at this tweak per Mrs. Laird's js. http://jsfiddle.net/KGCE5/ The issue is as described but Mrs. Laird is correct with default padding high charts uses for other html elements.